# How to run a program as adminstrator all the time?

Tags: windows

I have a program that needs to run as administrator to work properly. Sometimes I forget and run it without "Right as administrator" option. Is there a way to tell Windows that I want to run program X always as administrator?
I am running Windows 8.1 and logged in as a typical user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a Shortcut, get Properties > Shortcut > Advanced & check 'Run as Administrator'

[image]

Comment: Windows 8.1 has the same option